# c# export multiple list with a unique file

Tags: c#, list, import, export, uwp

I need export the values in multiple list and import values to multiple list at the same time i.e.  with one unique file, is this posible? and if is posible how?

I am new doing this and I have think create a list of list or an array of list.
The format file would xml, csv o json but if is json I would have to learn how to use.
My Project is a UWP but I think is no different in with a windows forms in lists, thanks for your answers in advice any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The new `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` is handy.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "abc", "bcd" };
var list2 = new List<int> { 123, 456 };

var xml = new XElement("save", new[]
{
    new XElement("list1",
        list1.Select(t => new XElement("text", t))),
    new XElement("list2",
        list1.Select(t => new XElement("value", t))),
});
File.WriteAllText("save.xml", xml.ToString());
```